# How to fix a GET JSON response problem in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im consuming a api from my React Native app. But the request response always returns a String and even when I try to parse im seeing a error.

I used axios, superagent and fetch api. But im still facing a error, the same one.

```
fetch(`http://fonte83.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&_embed`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
        }).then(result => result.json()).then(text => console.log(text))
```

This code works well on the navigator console or another application, but on my app is a mess. 
I another code I tried to convert in axios with this code, and still facing a error.

```
if (typeof data === 'string') {
             try {
                 if (!String.prototype.trim) {
                     String.prototype.trim = function () {
                         return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
                     };
                 }
                 data = JSON.parse(data.trim(''));
             } catch (e) {
                 throw {message: 'can not JSON.parse the response'}
             }
         }
```

Im receiving this error:
'Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0'.

These two code above are from different attempts

What is weird, because the code is working on other locations.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1):

Fetch API returns an JSON object on the Promise `result.json()`, so your code should be:

```
fetch(`http://fonte83.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&_embed`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    }).then(result => result.json())
      .then(obj => {
         console.log('Title of the first post: ' + obj[0].title.rendered);
         console.log('Content of the first post: ' + obj[0].content.rendered);
    });
```

You are trying to parse a object that was already parsed by `result.json()`

Comment: For sure... I undersante. But when I return 'result.json()', I receive this error: "'Unexpected token in JSON at position 0'.".

So I cannot forward with nothing.

Comment: @BrunnoHofmann maybe you're trying to access a property that doesn't exists. What do you get from `console.log(text)`?

Comment: Nothing. Because the code crash on result.json()

If I try the same code on another project it works fine :/.

I dont know if theres a http config or something, or even a React Native config.

Comment: @BrunnoHofmann please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/jpq1xc2o/ and see that code working. Open browser console to see the results.